# Yii dropdownlist depending on two dropdownlists

Tags: php, yii

I have seen [this wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/) where they populate a dropdownlist of cities, depending of the value of another dropdownlists that contains countries, using an ajax call with the update option. I need to implement something similar, but my dropdownlist depends on two dropdownlists:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::label('Countries', 'country_id'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropdownlist('country_id', '',$countries); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'globaladmin'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'globaladmin',User::itemAlias('AdminStatus')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'globaladmin'); ?>
</div>
```

The user must select a country, and then only if in the second list "No" is selected, a new dropdown lists must be populated with the cities info (just like in the wiki example).

As I said it is similar to the example, but the new dropdown depends on 2 values (the id of the contry selected on the first list and if "No" is selected in the second one). How could I solve it?

**EDIT: Explaining a little more**

In the example, the country dropdown which contains the ajax call is like:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('country_id','', array(1=>'USA',2=>'France',3=>'Japan'),
array(
'ajax' => array(
'type'=>'POST', //request type
'url'=>CController::createUrl('currentController/dynamiccities'), //url to call.
'update'=>'#city_id', //selector to update
)));
```

I can't define such a ajax call in my `country` list, because I must wait the value of the second dropbox. Only if "No" is selected in this list, the ajax will be executed (and the `city` dropdownlist populated and showed). If "Yes" is selected then the `city` dropdownlist must be hidden.

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem, Dont you can add your first and second dropdown values to your third ajax request?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour If you see the example, the ajax call that populates the `city` dropdown belongs to the `country` dropdown. Here I can't do that because I need the value of the `globaladmin` dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an ID to your globaladmin drop down and then do like below:

```
$("#THE ID YOU HAVE SET").on('change',function(){
    // You can use $(this).val()
    // and send it via an ajax request into your own url
    var valueOfMyGlobalAdminDropDown=$(this).val();
    if(valueOfMyGlobalAdminDropDown=="yes"){
       //DO SOMETHING
    }else{
       //DO SOMETHING ELSE
    }
});
```

it is also strongly recommended to use jquery live(in jquery version -1.7) or jquery ON(in jquery version +1.7) to keep your page alive in ajax requests.

Comment: Oh I get your idea! Just use regular jQuery ajax call instead of the  Yii-built-in, right?

Comment: Yes, right. In my personal view point, While using Yii, Most of times this is better to use ajax in another ways instead of Yii's default ajax behavior :)